# setup a sourceforge project with git from a local directory and now I cannot push the changes

Tags: git

Perhaps this has already been asked, but I have been looking for this answer all morning.
Because I develop on several computers, and on Windows and Linux, I figured I would setup a code repository on sourceforge.  I used git.  The original code is on one of my local machines.  Using the documentation given to me from the sourceforge website, I was able to originally commit the code.  I still modify the code locally on the original machine:  which is a Linux machine.  But, every time I attempt to push the changes to the sourceforge project, I get a message indicating the project is up to date:  despite making new changes to the code!  I tried to clone the code from the sourceforge site to the original directory, but when I do that, git tells me that I cannot do that, because the directory is not empty.  So, I create a new directory, clone the code from the sourceforge project, make the changes, and try to push to the sourceforge project (per the documentation), and I get the message indicating the project is up to date (like previous).

What am I doing wrong (besides the obvious of using the wrong tools).  Despite looking through all the git documentation on the git website and sourceforge, I still cannot seem to use as a code repository.

Any help would-->redirect to where this question has been answered previous would be appreciated.

```
$ git remote show -n
origin
$ git remote show -n <REMOTE>
remote <REMOTE> 
fetch URL:  <REMOTE>
push  URL:  <REMOTE>
HEAD Branch: (not queried)
Local ref configured for 'git push' (status not queried):
  (matching) pushes to (matching)
git remote show -n origin
* remote orgin
fetch URL: <REMOTE>
push URL:  <REMOTE>
HEAD Branch: (status not queried)
Remote Branch: (not queried)
  master
Local Branch configured for 'git pull':
   master merges with remote master
Local ref configured for 'git push' (status not queried):
   (matching) pushes to (matching)
```

Comment: if you are "obviously using the wrong tools", you might want to consider using the corrent ones.

Comment: apart from that: did you `commit` your changes to your local repository? try inspecting your repository with `gitk --all` to see the actual state of your local and the remote repository.

Comment: Thank you, but I do not have gitk...

Comment: Thank you...using gitk, I see the changes are committed to the local repository...but I cannot seem to update to the sourceforge.net directory...

Comment: do you have multiple remotes? what does `git remote show -n` tell you? what does `git remote show -n <REMOTE>` tell you (replacing <REMOTE> with each remote the previous cmd gave you). (please add that info to your question, rather than as a comment).

Comment: could you replace `<REMOTE>` with `origin` (as instructed) and rerun the last command again?